# module object has no attribute 'fblas' error when running theano.test() in Canopy Python

Tags: python-2.7, theano, enthought, canopy

I could not get Theano running in my system in Enthought canopy Python. When I give import theano and test run, I get the following error.

import blas
  File "/Users/rajesh/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/theano/tensor/blas.py", line 135, in 
    numpy.dtype('float32'):scipy.linalg.blas.fblas.sgemv,
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'fblas'

Can you please guide me the direction to resolve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's possibly because you installed an old version of Theano package. Try upgrade it or install the newest version by `pip install theano`.